# Add css class when user logged ng-class

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, meanjs

How can I use ng-class to add a Css class where I put `display: none;` when the user is log in?. I'm using mean.js so I first tried using

```
ng-show="authentication.user"
```

But that only makes the element to hide like `visivility : hidden;`

Besides I need to add other classes in elements that i keep rather if the user is logged or not where I change margins and other stuff.

I tried using in angular a condition:

```
$scope.logged = false;
if ($scope.authentication.user) {
      $scope.logged = true;
}
```

and then adding the ng-class condition like this:

```
ng-class="logged ? 'myClass1' : 'myClass2'"
```

But it failed, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-if="authentication.user"
```

will remove the element altogether unlike ng-show which hides it.

Comment: that solves my first problem of removing an element. But what happen when I have to make changes in css properties of elements that I keep both when is or not the user logged?

Answer (score 0):

With AngularJS, the right syntax is :

`ng-class="{ className : Boolean}"`

A example with multiple classes from [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) :

```
ng-class="{strike: deleted, bold: important, 'has-error': error}"
```

Or with a function :

```
ng-class="{ invalid : !form.validPassword()}"
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I don't know what am i doing wrong, but the ng-class is not getting the value from the $scope, I print out the value with console.log() and is change like expected but the ng-class is not getting the value for some reason.

Comment: Do you pass the controller in a parent div, `<div ng-controller="myController"> `, so the child element will see the $scope

Comment: Yes, I have it just above of where I need it. Actually I put a checkobox to see the ng-class beheivour and it does change the class, I just don't get why in does it with the checkbox and not with the scope.